# How to get DateTime.TryParse to parse dates in the "ddMMyyyy" format?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to parse dates that might be in the format "ddMMyyyy" as well as in the standard GB English formats (e.g. "dd/mm/yyyy"), and I'm trying to use the `DateTime.TryParse()` method to do it but it doesn't recognise the "ddMMyyyy" format.

I know I can use `Date.TryParseExact()` and specify the custom format each time, but that means doing two checks for each date (one for the custom format and one for the culture's standard formats) and it just seems that there must be a better way.

Is there a way to get the `DateTime.TryParse()` method to recognise custom date formats as well as the standard formats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it's possible to set `DateTime.TryParse()` to recognize any of two date formats **at the same time**. Looking at the overrides for `DateTime.TryParse()` you have `.TryParse(String, DateTime)` and `TryParse(String, IFormatProvider, DateTimeStyles, DateTime)`, therefore the maximum of flexibility here lets you provide a `IFormatProvider` that could be a `DateTimeFormatInfo` class, but `DateTimeFormatInfo` can only deal with one set of formats at a time.

One shot (I did not try it) would be to create a new `DateTimeFormatInfo` class with different LongDatePattern and ShortDatePattern patterns (matching the ones you want to use), and pass the instance as a parameter to `TryParse`, but checking two times with `Date.TryParseExact()` seems way more reasonable.

Comment: OK, that makes sense about the `DateTimeFormatInfo` class only dealing with  one set of formats at a time, thanks. But how does the `DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime)` method interpret more than one short date at a time? e.g. both dd-MM-yyyy and dd/MM/yyyy get parsed correctly.

Comment: Since the `DateTimeFormatInfo.DateSeparator` property is a simple string (not an array of separators), and `DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime)` uses your current `CultureInfo` class, my best guess is that `DateTime.TryParse(String, DateTime)` in case of failure, tries to replace the - separator with the / separator to see if it can find a match against the current `CultureInfo`.

Answer (score 0):

Howw about using DateTime.TryParseExact
[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx)

Comment: He said he knows about this method, he want to know if there are any alternative to avoid calling to different methods to parse the two date formats.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that date parsers tend not to be too intelligent, mostly by design. While you may want to parse a `"ddMMyyyy"` date, someone else may want to parse a `"yyyyMMdd"` date. In some circumstances, these may be identical (what is `"20121220"`?). The parser is dumb, and you must tell it which format to use. If you specify multiple formats, then it'd need to try them one at a time, which is exactly what you are trying to avoid.

If you really only want to take a single pass, you could use a regex to extract the pertinent parts (`"(?<Day>\d{2})/?(?<Month>\d{2})/?(?<Year>\d{4})"`) then reconstitute it into a format recognized by the parser (`string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", match.Groups["Day"].Value, match.Groups["Month"].Value, match.Groups["Year"].Value)`).

Honestly, though, it'd probably be more efficient to just use String.Contains("/") in an `if` statement.